# Define Root Folder for Project Sites

Tags: html, css, wamp, root

I am using WAMP and I have multiple site projects.

When accessing files within my CSS or HTML I'd like to use the root selector `/index.html` however this is not working.  Is there a way I can define root for a project?  I've tried researching this but haven't found anything.

For example, in WAMP I have

-www/project1/FOLDERS FOR SITE like images, javascript, css, etc.

I am currently in the css folder and am trying to reference a image file in the images folder.

```
background: url('/images/background.png') repeat;
```

this should reference `root directory > images > background.png`

How do I define the root directory?

Comment: Please elaborate. Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean not working? It would be helpful if you put some code.

Comment: A file cannot be a root. The default root is `/`. What do you mean by root selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are try to go from lets say this file:
rootFolder/newFolder/example.html

to:
rootFolder/index.html

In example.html, you can do ../index.html and that will be able to access index.html.
"../" goes a folder higher.

Comment: right but I want to start again at the root folder.  using just / but its not working in wamp (my local server)

Comment: I dont know why "/" is not working but you're best bet would be to do "../" however many times you need to get to the root folder

Comment: I was mistaken.  I thought it was possible to just type in / and I would go to the master root of the site.